Contactless AC Detector Powered from the Grid
I'm a newbie in electrical engineering, and I'm working on an IoT project where the IoT board is wired to a relay that can turn a load on and off. To make things more interesting, I want to notify the user if the main switch (which is wired in series with the relay to the load) is turned off. In that case, activating the relay would be pointless.
The following image will help clarify things:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
(The antenna is around 10 cm long)
After searching online, I found this AC detection circuit:

Image took from here: Antenna for contactless 50/60Hz AC detector
It works really well when powered by batteries. However, when I try to power the board from a power supply, it seems like the detector is picking up AC signals everywhere. (I even disassembled a Voltstick to power it the same way, with the same results as expected).
I suspect this might be due to a difference in potential relative to ground or some kind of ground loop issue. This makes sense because if I touch the earth and the negative terminal of the circuit, the detector works fine again.
To address this, I bought a DC-DC galvanic isolator (B0505S-1W) and wired it between the board and the detector, but this didn’t help. I believe grounding the circuit to earth might fix it, but I don’t see this as the best or most elegant solution.
Is there another way to isolate or remove these ground interference issues?
edit: fixed LED symbol
edit with further explanation:
The load is an AC unit controlled by the IoT board via an IR transmitter, and the board is powered by a USB wall adapter. Even though it's possible to turn off the AC unit with the IR transmitter, I also want the ability to fully power it off, which is why I use the relay. The AC unit is wired with a wall switch, as shown in the diagram, and I really want to preserve the switch because I occasionally use it.
As mentioned earlier, when I try to turn on the AC unit, change the temperature, or make any other request, I want the board to notify me that the request has failed because the switch is off. Since I didn’t want to wire components directly to the high-voltage AC line, I opted for a contactless AC detector with an optocoupler connected to the board and wired in parallel with the LED in the diagram. By reading the photodiode of the optocoupler, I can tell if the AC unit is receiving power.

what's the purpose of the photodiode?

@jsotola it's probably supposed to be an LED.

Which connection your device has to mains? Wired directly by an electrician, or mains plug? Which type of mains plug, UK, Schuko, something else - main point is if it is polarized or non-polarized plug. Also this is an XY problem. You have a problem X which is a need to detect mains presence, and you have already decided to solve it with Y which is a contactless AC detect circuit, and you are asking how to make Y work with a lot of effort invested in it already, while you could just use a better method for detecting AC mains presence to begin with.

Not the most elegant solution, but a very small relay with the coil powered from the switched mains line would give you indication without having to deal with (as many) isolation issues.

The threshold of your internet AC detect circuit is very low and the bandwidth is way more than 60Hz .This means that it is easy for it to pick up rubbish like common mode SMPS hash .If you do some homework and sort out a narrow band scheme with a variable threshold then wireless power detection could work which means no high voltage connections.
